# Re-assignment of Partition gets infinitely stuck in "Still in progress" state

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have 6 node kafka cluster. Out of the 6 machines, 3 of them have both Kafka + zookeeper, and the remaining 3 of them have just kafka.
Recently, we added one more kafka node. While re-assigning the partition to all the nodes (including the newer one), we executed the below command:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --reassignment-json-file new_assignment_details.json --execute --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

However, when we verified the status by using the below command,

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --reassignment-json-file new_assignment_details.json --verify --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

We get the below output. Some of the partitions are re-assignment is still in progress.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --reassignment-json-file new_assignment_details.json --verify --zookeeper localhost:2181 | grep 'progress'
Reassignment of partition [topic-name,854] is still in progress
Reassignment of partition [topic-name,674] is still in progress
Reassignment of partition [topic-name,944] is still in progress
Reassignment of partition [topic-name,404] is still in progress
Reassignment of partition [topic-name,314] is still in progress
Reassignment of partition [topic-name,853] is still in progress
Reassignment of partition [prom-metrics,403] is still in progress
Reassignment of partition [prom-metrics,134] is still in progress
```

There is no way to either:

1. Cancel the on-going partition re-assignment.
2. Rollback is also not possible. ( When we try doing that it says that **"There is an existing assignment running."**

**Kafka Version: 0.10.1.1**

**Platform: Amazon Linux 1 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Can anyone please help me out in this?

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel the on-going partition re-assignment by deleting the zk node: delete /admin/reassign_partitions.
Then you can rollback or reassign with another json file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for canceling current partition re-assignment and being able to perform another re-assignment you should:

1. Delete `/admin/reassign_partitions` zk node
2. Delete `/controller` zk node to re-elect the active controller

**UPDATE**
consider using `--additional` argument of kafka-reassign-partitions.sh!

Answer (score 0):

Following on @Mostafa-Bayat, version `0.10` is very old and administration is manual and error prone. The AdminAPI was included in kafka 2.6 (I believe) and improved in following version. (see [KIP-236](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-236%3A+Interruptible+Partition+Reassignment))

Everyone should be on the latest 2.x ([2.8.1](https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/2.8.1/RELEASE_NOTES.html) at time of writing) or latest 3.x ([3.2.1](https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/3.2.1/RELEASE_NOTES.html) currently) to take advantage of the adminapi that makes reassignments possible with `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` without manual edits in zookeeper. (3.x is working to remove zk entirely).